# Lightning Components Do NOT Use React?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, appexchange, isv, security-review

The combination of Lightning Component and React is NG?
Is my understanding of this correct?

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist

> Use of third party MV * frameworks is not currently supported with
>   Lightning. Any Lightning package that uses Angular or React or other
>   third party DOM-based templating frameworks will automatically fail
>   the security review until such time as we provide custom lightning
>   components to properly encapsulate these frameworks. This is to avoid
>   template injection attacks resulting from double interpolation. In
>   order to use another framework as part of a package that uses
>   Lightning, please use an iframe or Visualforce container until
>   approved Lightning containers are published.

Comment: If you want to use React and SLDS, check out https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct. Please use only one framework (Lightning). If you want to use React, you can do so in an iframe or in a VF page. If we do support React in the future, it would be with a custom component to properly separate it our from Lightning.

UPDATE: I'd like to point out that we may well support React and other frameworks in the future. In this case, please check the Requirements Checklist and our Secure Coding guidelines for lists of approved third party frameworks and secure usage instructions.

Comment: Is jquery or vanilla javascript is allowed ?

Comment: You have to use javascript with lightning components @MohithShrivastava.

Comment: yes, jQuery is allowed. of course vanilla javascript is allowed. But be careful to conform to the framework lifecycle (e.g. DOM is read only in the controllers, DOM rendering should be put into a renderer, etc)

Comment: What is the difference of React and jQuery and the other framework ? Why OK with jQuery and why automatically bad with React ? It is too headstrong. Is it your ability of checking the framework you can't understand ?

Comment: Now see some components are using D3.js and it is accessing SVG DOM with their own template engine. That is what the React is doing essentially. Any difference ? Capsulation is our matter, and we can safely do it by browserify or webpack. Not the platform's business.

Comment: jQuery micro templating does not use DOM based templating engines. As to why we are so restrictive,  the problem is that you have no idea how many other components are being loaded onto the same DOM, which frameworks *they* are using, and how *they* are handling encapsulation. And your component has to work safely along side all the others (and our production UI).  If you find this too restrictive, you have the option of 1) integrating less tightly via a connected app or VF page, or 2) Limiting development to your own org rather than publishing your component to the Appexchange.

Comment: Can you expand on the *why* of this rule? I don't understand the difference between React and any Javascript library that may be included like jQuery and D3? Is the concern that the developer is going to target the wrong div with their top level React.render (Couldn't the security review team validate that?) ? I don't see why this concern is limited to React and Angular, the bigger concern seems to be any js that mutates the dom? I think this deserves a little bit more clarification as we have been pitched from Day 1 of Lightning components that we can use whatever UI framework we want.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to do my React.render in the lightning render lifecycle method as a replacement to the document.createElement in this tutorial: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-4 . I'd just be returning a complex node instead of a simple node.

Comment: @RobertSussland The attempt of Lightning to control all of the timing of updating the DOM is so impractical - for example, jQuery sometimes asynchronously updates DOM attributes in their animation experiment. It seems a design flaw as a SPA framework if it is really intended. By restricting the update only for the DOM node which is not controlled by Lightning is much practical (this is what I'm doing currently, and safely working).

Comment: Moar commentary required plz

Comment: Still can't use react for lighting experience yet?

Comment: React apps stop working with LockerService enabled at the moment. Lots of bugs still. Initial render is working fine but once you need to reconcile the DOM it throws all kinds of errors. I dug deep into it and figured out that React uses Node.nextSibling but when LockerService is enabled, calling Node.nextSibling always returns null. And that's not the only issue, just one of them. I really hope all of that will be sorted out before we are enforced to activate the LockerService update.

Comment: Any updates? It's almost 2018. I'd pay half of my life to get this working.

Comment: With the introduction of LockerService, you can use anything that you can get to work -- not all third party frameworks will work in strict mode and with the CSP, but many will. This was true since API version 40 and above.