# Is it possible to hook into several controllers from an aura component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I know that I can hook a component/app to a controller like this:

```
<aura:component controller="IncidentsController">
</aura:component>
```

However, is it possible to get this component to communicate with more than one controller?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.. In VF page as well we use extension for multiple controllers.. But I am commenting here because I am not sure.

Comment: Can I use an extension with aura?

Comment: I don't think so...but what exactly are you trying to accomplish...what is the logic you want to put in the "extension" as opposed to the controller?

Comment: I have a lightning component which includes javascript which is basically a React + Flux application. I can communicate with the Apex server using the lightning component. However, I can only communicate with 1 controller. If I need to communicate with a different controller, I will need to a add another component just so it will associated with a different controller. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Based on this post you can't do that unless I am misunderstanding. I want to do the similar thing but with remote object. But after my research I only can implement lighting component with aura. I hope I am wrong. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100412/lightning-components-do-not-use-react

Answer (score 7):

Yes and No , no way so far for multiple apex controllers link to one aura component. but component allows include child components or inherited from 
super component. Each component has one controller.

using inheritance

```
<!-- BaseComponent -->
<aura:component extensible="true" controller="BaseComponentController">
</aura:component>

<!-- child component -->
<aura:component extends="BaseComponent" 
controller="childComponentController">
</aura:component>
```

Invoke Base component helper method from child component, then invoke BaseComponentController methods.

for example in childhelper.js

```
doStuff: function(component,event, helper){
  //call base component helper deleteRecord method
  helper.deleteRecord(component);

  //call apex childComponentController method doStuff
  var action = component.get("c.doStuff");

}
```

in basecomponentHelper.js

```
deleteRecord : function(component){
   var baseCmp = component.getConcreteComponent();
   //call apex BaseComponentController delRecord function
   var action = baseCmp.get('c.delRecord');

}
```

or adapt the same idea to invoke Apex controller from child component.

Comment: Very inflexible design...

Answer (score 5):

I think your best option is using component.find and helper components:

```
<aura:component>
   <c:OpportunitiesSelector aura:id="oppsHelper" />
   <c:ContactsSelector aura:id="conHelper" />
   <ui:button press="{!c.doSomething}" label="Do Something" />
</aura:component>
```

Then in controller you'd go:

```
doSomething : function (component) {
    var action = component.find('oppsHelper').get('c.getOppsById');
    action.setParams({
        ids: [123456789012345678, 098765432187654321]
    });
    var action2 = component.find('conHelper').get('c.getContactsByEmail');
    action2.setParams({
        email: 'foo@baz.qux'
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    $A.enqueueAction(action2);
}
```

All your OpportunitiesSelector has to have is:

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunitiesSelector" />
```

Comment: One of the patterns that followed from this outlined here: https://github.com/metacursion/sfdc-lax-benedict
Also now with LWC you can create such service components without using any libraries!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use two Apex controller in Lightning Component, but you can Extends the Component and use Super Component controller action in sub component.Look at this blog

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html

However do not call Super component controller action in Sub component, because I found one note in Developer Guide

> We don't recommend using inheritance of client-side controllers as this feature may be deprecated in the future to preserve better component encapsulation. We recommend that you put common code in a helper instead.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing multiple Server-Side Apex controllers Classes within a Lightning Component is not supported. I don't have a specific reference to support that statement, but consider this from [the Lightning Components Developers Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm). When we want to call a Server-Side Action from a component, we make a reference to the method in the client side controller like this:

```
    // create a one-time use instance of the serverEcho action
    // in the server-side controller
    var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
```

> The cmp.get("c.serverEcho") call indicates that we’re calling the serverEcho >method in the server-side controller. The method name in the server-side >controller must match everything after the c. in the client-side call. In this >case, that’s serverEcho.

SO... if we want to make references to two different Server-Side Apex controller Classes, we would need a means to identify the two Apex Classes as, let's say, "c1" and "c2". Only then would we be able to make a reference methods from one or the other... that's currently not supported.

Does somebody want to create an Idea in the Idea Exchange?